# Bootstrap validation is showing red after selecting date using asp.net text box control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap validation is showing red after selecting date using asp.net text box control.

Below is image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVann.png)

Below is design code:

```
<label class="control-label">Training Start Date</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_TrainingStartDate" runat="server" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Training Start Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Below is jquery scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker')
    .datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    })
       .on('changeDate', function(e) {
           // Revalidate the date field
           $('#form1').formValidation('revalidateField', "<%=txt_TrainingStartDate.UniqueID %>");
       });

    });

 </script>
```

Below is boostrap validation script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'fa fa-check',
                invalid: 'fa fa-times',
                validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            },
            fields: {



                <%=txt_TrainingStartDate.UniqueID%>: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Select Date is required and can\'t be empty'
                        } 
                    }
                } 


            }
        });

    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: i think you want txt_TrainingStartDate.ClientID instead of txt_TrainingStartDate.UniqueID